# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindValue()

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have a problem on SQL query which contains bindValue.
The error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindValue() on bool (240).

But I can't see any problem in the codes. Help pls :/

```
$count = $db->query("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE title LIKE :search");
$count->bindValue(":search","%{$search}%",PDO::PARAM_STR); // (line:240)
$count->execute();
```

Comment: `PDO::query()` returns a PDOStatement object, or FALSE on failure. You should be using `PDO::prepare()` instead if you're using `bindValue`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use the function `bindValue()` you want to work with a prepared statement. So instead of calling `query()`, use `prepare()`.

```
$count = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE title LIKE :search");
$count->bindValue(":search","%{$search}%",PDO::PARAM_STR);
$count->execute();
```